# Does if loop work in OnpostExecute in Android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

So i converted a JSOn object and compared the value with something,and even though the value matches with whats there in the string,the loop is not getting invoked,this what i've written
Any help would be appreciated

```
@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {

            JSONObject obj = null;
            try {
                obj = new JSONObject(s);
                String error_desc = obj.getString("error_desc");
                writeToFile("responseONP="+error_desc);
                if(error_desc == "Invalid Credentials") {
                    Context context = getApplicationContext();
                    CharSequence text = error_desc;
                    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                    toast.show();
                }

                else{
                     Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), HomepageNormal.class);
                     startActivity(intent);
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: Show some sample data.

Comment: try this in your if condtion error_desc.equalsIgnoreCase("Invalid Credentials")

Comment: instead of `==` use `.equals()` for Compare String object

Comment: @Venky let me know if that works for you

Comment: please observe that if != loop

Comment: .equals works,thanks a lot everyone for helping